# Piano tiles: background image

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make piano tiles in python using pygame. So, I've started with making an intro window but I'm unable to upload a background image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPbQk.jpg) in my into window. I actually want to display the name 'Piano tiles' and the background image whenever the player starts the game. Here's my code:

```
import pygame,os,random,time
from pygame.locals import *
wix=800
wiy=800
pygame.init()
white=(255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 100)
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((wix,wiy))
bg = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")
pygame.display.set_caption("Piano Tiles")
def game_intro():
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((wix,wiy))
    intro =True
    while intro:
        bg = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")
        screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        message_to_screen("PIANO TILES",black,-100,"large")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(8)

def text_objects(text,color,size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)


    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
def message_to_screen(msg,color, y_displace=0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color, size)
    textRect.center = (wix/ 2), (wiy / 2)+y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

game_intro()
pygame.time.wait(4000)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: remove `fill(white)` or use it before `screen.blit` BTW you don't have to load the same image milions times in `while` loop - load it before loop.

Comment: and use `screen` instead `gameDisplay` - `gameDisplay` may be different surface than `screen` . you don't have to use `set_mode` two times.

Comment: It worked! thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `fill(white)` before you `blit` anything because it clear screen.

It could look like this

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WIX = 800
WIY = 800

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
RED   = (255,  0,  0)
GREEN = (  0,155,  0)

FPS = 8

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        text_font = small_font
    elif size == "medium":
        font = med_font
    elif size == "large":
        font = large_font

    #fonts = {"small": small_font, "medium": med_font, "large": large_font}
    #font = fonts[size]

    text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()

    return text_surface, text_rect

def message_to_screen(screen, msg, color, y_displace=0, size="small"):
    text_surface, text_rect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    text_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
    text_rect.y += y_displace
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

def game_intro(screen, text):
    #bg = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")

    screen.fill(WHITE) # use if background is smaller then screen

    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))

    message_to_screen(screen, text, BLACK, -100, "large")
    message_to_screen(screen, text, BLACK, 0, "large")
    message_to_screen(screen, text, BLACK, 100, "large")

    pygame.display.update()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False # exit program
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return True # go to next stage
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    return True # go to next stage

        clock.tick(FPS)

# --- main --- (lower_case names) 

# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIX, WIY))
#screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("Piano Tiles")

# - resources -

bg = pygame.image.load("Obrazy/test.png")#"background.jpg")

small_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
med_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
large_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 100)

#fonts = {"small": small_font, "medium": med_font, "large": large_font}

# - stages -

go_next = game_intro(screen, "HELLO WORLD")
if go_next:
    go_next = game_intro(screen, "PIANO TILES")
if go_next:
    go_next = game_intro(screen, "BYE, BYE")

# - exit -

pygame.quit()
```